# a special condition about vibrating string problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following problem

> $$  \begin{align}\begin{cases} u_{tt} - 4 u_{xx} =0   & t > 0 , 0 < x
>  < 3\pi \\  u(0,t) = -\pi,  u(3\pi, t) = 2\pi &  t> 0   \\ u(x,0) = 0 ,
>  u_{t}(x,0) = 0 & 0 < x < 3\pi  \end{cases} \end{align} $$

In fact I do not know how to fix with $u_{t}(x,0) = 0$

Comment: Huh???  The posed question wants a solution involving $y$ but there is no $y$ in the question!!

Comment: General idea is to introduce a reference function $r(x,t)$ such that $u(x,t) = v(x,t) +r(x,t)$

Answer (score 1):

If you let
$$
    v(x,t)=u(x,t)+(\pi-x),
$$
then $v_{tt}-4v_{xx}=0$. However, unlike for $u$, $v$ satisfies homogeneous conditions at $x=0,3\pi$:
$$v(0,t)=u(0,t)+\pi=0 \\
  v(3\pi,t)=u(3\pi,t)+(\pi-3\pi)=0.
$$
That makes separation of variables work for $v$. The initial conditions become
$$
    v(x,0)=u(x,0)+(\pi-x)=\pi-x\\
    v_t(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0.
$$
The separated solution is
$$
       v(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n\cos(2n\pi t/3)+B_n\sin(2n\pi t/3))\sin(n\pi x/3).
$$
The condition $v_t(x,0)=0$ forces all $B_n=0$. The condition $v(x,0)=\pi-x$ determines the $A_n$:
$$
    \pi-x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x/3).
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the homogeneous wave equation with non-homogeneous boundary conditions like below

$$  \begin{align}\begin{cases} u_{tt} - c^{2} u_{xx} =0   & t > 0 , 0 < x  < L \\  u(0,t) = \phi(t),  u(L, t) = \psi(t) &  t> 0   \\ u(x,0) = f(x) ,  u_{t}(x,0) = g(x) & 0 < x < L  \end{cases} \end{align} $$

you introduce a reference function $r(x,t)$ such that $u(x,t) = v(x,t) +r(x,t)$ where $v(x,t)$ is a function satisifying the homogeneous solution and $r(x,t)$ satisfies the nonhomogeneous boundary conditions.

To do this we can make $r(x,t)$ the following function

$$ r(x,t) = \frac{x}{L}\left[ \psi(t) - \phi(t) \right] + \phi(t)$$

in this case, your $r(x,t)$ isn't time-dependent and we can write is as

$$ r(x) = \frac{x}{3\pi}\left[ 2\pi - (-\pi) \right] - \pi = \frac{3\pi x}{3\pi} - \pi = x - \pi$$

then your $v(x,t)$ is the homogeneous solution as usual which is

$$ v(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( A_{n} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{3\pi})\cos(\frac{2 n\pi t}{3\pi} )+ B_{n} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{3\pi}) \sin(\frac{2 n \pi t}{3\pi})\bigg) $$

which can be reduced as

$$ v(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( A_{n} \sin(\frac{n x}{3})\cos(\frac{2 n t}{3}) + B_{n} \sin(\frac{n x}{3}) \sin(\frac{2 n  t}{3})\bigg) $$

$$ v(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( A_{n} \cos(\frac{2 n t}{3}) + B_{n} \sin(\frac{2 n  t}{3})\bigg)\sin(\frac{n x}{3}) $$